# exec a php to execute shell script

Tags: php

I have a php script like this.
This doesn't run my script nor print anything on the click of the button. How to do that
Also if you have a pointer to php 101 online please let me know

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
ob_start();

passthru("./check_ddts.sh ".escapeshellarg($_POST["CSCui21515"]));
$data = ob_get_clean();
}
?>


<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<button type="button" onclick="?run=true">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: where do you define your functions `passthru()` and `escapeshellarg()`?

Comment: @Dave `passthru()` and `escapeshellarg()` are native php functions.

Comment: Really? Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Your button is not actually doing anything. The problem is that your onclick attribute should contain javascript which will run when the button is clicked, not a redirect location. Use a form with a submit button instead like this.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="run" value="Click Me!" />
</form>
```

I notice in your question that you are also using post data in handling the form, in which case the above will not work. You need to submit the `POST` data at the same time as you run the script.